# Add-in for Office Excel Web App

Tags: web-applications, web, ms-office, add-in

1. Do you know how to add any ADD-IN to office web apps (esp: Excel)?
2. Is it possible or not?
3. How can I add some features that are not currently in default office web app (e.g:sky drive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do applications for some webapps in the same way you develop applications for Office 2013 but Web Apps only support some application types:

1. Excel Web App Supports only Content Application types
2. Outlook Web App Supports only Mail Application types

For more information you can check [Types of apps for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220082%28v=office.15%29#StartBuildingApps_TypesofApps)

If you need a tutorial, first you need an account in [Office 365 Developer Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179924).
Then you can create your first  [Excel Web App Content Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220065?lc=1033) using 'napa'